# How to detach this connector?

Tags: kia, connector, picanto

Can any of you kindly let me know what Connectors this is and how to remove it ?

I have to remove this connector in order to Access my Throttle body below the engine hood.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please find the pictures of the underside of the connector.

https://ibb.co/CQ1CnS4

https://ibb.co/mC4vbgY

https://ibb.co/qL8x38G

It Says Delphi PA66-GF30

Kia Picanto 2018 Model.

Comment: It is not what connector it is but how to take it apart. Can’t be sure as none of your images show - but there will be a clip to lift or press then pull the connector off. Do NOT pull on the wires.

Comment: Add a photo to the underside of the connector.

Comment: Add details of the car make and model.

Comment: In the first picture you can see a slot in the top of the corrector and a T-shaped thing in the slot. Press down hard on the T (e.g. with a screwdriver) and pull the connector over it. When you refit the connector it will click into place to lock it.

Comment: @alephzero - That's an alignment notch, not a latch. The latch will be on the underside.

Comment: I will also say its a good idea to try and find another connector that you can see the "under" side of.  Manufacturers like to use the same style connectors for multiple jobs, so a similar connector thats easier to get to could "show you the way".

Answer (score 8):

Push or pull the gray thingy.

[image]

The connector should then unlock.

Comment: Please find the pictures of the underside of the connector.

https://ibb.co/CQ1CnS4

https://ibb.co/mC4vbgY

https://ibb.co/qL8x38G

It Says Delphi PA66-GF30

Comment: OK, nice pics. Did you try the "gray thingy"?